# Companions lost on death in same room as other explorers

Tags: betrayal-at-house-on-the-hill

I understand the general ruling on companions lost on death. Essentially it says "whomever enters the room first gains custody of the companion". However, this doesn't quite make sense for the scenario I'm in right now: two heros and the traitor are in a room. One hero has the madman, and dies fighting the traitor. Now the madman, last hero and traitor are all in the same room. Who gets the madman? We eventually decided that you had to move out of the room and back into the room to take the madman, since that's what the rules seem to say, but that seems illogical.

Tl;dr if a companion is in the same room as two explorers, who gets the companion?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What happens to companions when a player dies?](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/18750/what-happens-to-companions-when-a-player-dies)

Comment: This is _not_ a duplicate of that question; please don't close it! That other question was simple - asker hadn't noticed a paragraph in the rules; answerer points it out. This question on the other hand follows up with what appears to be a true ambiguity in the rules.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rules as written do seem to imply you have to leave the room and re-enter. However I agree with you that this is silly - the spirit of the rules as I read them is that the lost companion gloms on to the first available explorer. So to resolve the ambiguity I would house-rule the relevant section:

> If another explorer enters the room **or starts their turn in the room**, he or she gains custody of that companion.

Or if you prefer more instantaneous glomming,

> **If one or more other explorers are already in the room, the next in turn order gains custody of that companion immediately**. Otherwise, the next explorer to enter the room does.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I expected to hear. Otherwise, I'd have to waste two movement to leave the room containing the traitor, one more to re-enter the room, and another two to leave again. That seems absurd. I'll add the house rule next time I play. Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

I would say whoever picks up the token. So you would put the madman aside and then the next player able to "pick up" the madman would gain custody. They sort of hint towards that with the item pile

> Any other items you have drop to the floor. Put an Item Pile token there and set aside their cards. Other explorers can go to the room to pick up your items (and take these cards)

Comment: The rule you're quoting is _explicitly_ about everything _other_ than companions. Though since there's no rule that actually addresses our case, I suppose applying this rule is one valid solution.

Comment: Yes I know that but that rule is also directly AFTER companions. My point was to suggest that I think they meants for the "pick up" action to also apply to companions but like many of the rules questions in Betrayal it suffered from poor writing.

Answer (score -2):

Here is an option for you....
What if the companion will attach to the last person in the room.  If its multiple friendlies, you could agree on someone leaving the room, if enemies, well it looks like we have a fight on our hand!

However that may just seem to aide the aggressor in most scenarios.

Comment: But who does it attach to when there's both sides in one room?